# Which command can I use to delete a Vertex AI pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have loads of Vertex AI pipeline runs. The GUI only lets me delete them one at a time. Is there a CLI command that lets me delete them in batch (ideally keeping the most recent)?

Comment: It seems deleting a pipeline using CLI is not feasible at this point.But you can achieve the same by using Vertex AI SDK for Python or Java as  mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-delete-training-pipeline-sample). For multiple pipelines you can use a loop and pass their IDs to the function.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: yes, thanks. If you want to create an answer i will accept it.

Comment: This is not the first time I complain about GCP and I think it explains why it is not the leader in cloud industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems deleting a pipeline using CLI is not feasible at this point. But you can achieve the same by using the Vertex AI SDK for Python or Java as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-delete-training-pipeline-sample). For multiple pipelines, you can use a loop and pass their IDs to the function.